# An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.commit. Not initialized

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have a glue job that parses csv file uploaded to S3 and persist data to rds instance. It was working fine. But one day there occurred an error

> An error occurred while calling
> z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.commit. Not initialized.

How can I resolve this? I haven't made any changes in the script or anywhere. The python version used is 3, glue version 2. Somebody please help.

Comment: The same error happen to me. No modification made on the job/script ...

Comment: Maybe some aws issue? Check personal health dashboard for any recent notifications or events.

Comment: But I need to enable job-bookmark option. Since everyday I have new files to upload and it should not parse data if it is already done.

Comment: Hi All ,  It is found that temp folder is mapped to S3://<bucket name>/<user> in the already created job. In the S3 bucket inside <user> folder partitionlisting folder is also there. So when I changed the temp folder upto partitionlist it worked. Anyone please help.......

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the Job Bookmark seemed to have fixed this for me. In the Console, select the Glue Job -> Action -> Reset job bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the error is caused by the `--job-bookmark-option` parameter.

If you have a workflow you can use the following code in order to iterate all the job and disable the bookmark options.

In other case, you can add the parameter/disable the bookmark manually from the UI of Glue

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/glue"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func FixJob(glueConnection *glue.Client) {
    // Create a Glue client with additional configuration
    jobs, err := glueConnection.ListJobs(context.Background(), &glue.ListJobsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, job := range jobs.JobNames {
        fmt.Println(job)
        getJob, err := glueConnection.GetJob(context.Background(), &glue.GetJobInput{JobName: &job})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        indent, err := json.MarshalIndent(getJob, " ", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Fixing the following job: " + string(indent))

        // POSSIBLE FIX FOR THE PROBLEM
        getJob.Job.DefaultArguments["--job-bookmark-option"] = "job-bookmark-disable"

        j := getJob.Job
        var connectionName string

        if _, err = glueConnection.UpdateJob(context.Background(), &glue.UpdateJobInput{
            JobName: j.Name,
            JobUpdate: &gluetypes.JobUpdate{
                Command:                 j.Command,
                Connections:             &gluetypes.ConnectionsList{Connections: []string{connectionName}},
                DefaultArguments:        j.DefaultArguments,
                Description:             j.Description,
                ExecutionProperty:       j.ExecutionProperty,
                GlueVersion:             j.GlueVersion,
                LogUri:                  j.LogUri,
                MaxRetries:              0,
                NonOverridableArguments: j.NonOverridableArguments,
                NotificationProperty:    j.NotificationProperty,
                NumberOfWorkers:         aws.Int32(2),
                Role:                    j.Role,
                SecurityConfiguration:   j.SecurityConfiguration,
                Timeout:                 j.Timeout,
                WorkerType:              j.WorkerType,
            },
        }); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lmicroseconds | log.Llongfile)
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    glueConnection := glue.New(glue.Options{Credentials: cfg.Credentials, Region: cfg.Region})
    FixJob(glueConnection)
}
```